# Is the meaning of this phrase correct?

Tags: meaning

I want to say the phrase "I can understand about 60% of the content of this video" in japanese. I translated it to:

このビデオの内容は６０％ぐらい分かれます。

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off your attempt:

> このビデオの内容は６０％ぐらい分かれます。

This attempt is incorrect but probably comprehensible to your listener. First, there is no possibility conjugation of 分かる or if you prefer 分かる like 入る already includes the normal sense of possibility in it.

Second, let's think about the aspect you're stating this in. 60% means that you're either measuring how much you believe you've understood (in the past) or you're estimating it in an ongoing fashion.

Third, stating 60% by itself might sound a bit overly-precise, so it seems wise to use a couching expression (ぼかし表現) to make this a bit softer.

So I might suggest:

> このビデオは６割ぐらいわかりました。

= I understood about 60% of the video.

or

> このビデオの内容はほぼ６０％理解できる。

= I am able to understand about 60% of the video's contents.

Comment: I didn't know about 割 to express percentage, is very useful

Answer (score 1):

分かれる is an intransitive verb meaning "to split or divide." The verb わかる (usually written without the kanji) encompasses the meaning "able to understand." If you want to emphasize "can comprehend," you can use the Sino-Japanese word and say 理解できる。Keep in mind that 理解する, unlike わかる, is a transitive verb, although this is irrelevant in your sentence because the object is topicalized. There are also some nuances in meaning and formality differences between 理解 and わかる that you can read about, e.g., [here](https://www.italki.com/question/156645).

Comment: So the correct sentence would be like this? 私はこのビデオの内容は６０％ぐらいを理解できる。

Comment: @Lua 「このビデオの内容は６０％ぐらい理解できる/できます。」のほうがいいです（with no を after ぐらい）。 「このビデオの内容は６０％ぐらい分か**り**ます。」でもいいです。If you need to add 私は：「私はこのビデオの内容を60％ぐらい理解できます。」「私はこのビデオの内容が60％ぐらいわかります。」

Comment: @Chocolate はい、わかりました。ありがとう！「理解する」は他動詞と思ったから、「を」助詞を加えました。

Comment: @Lua Yes, you can use を with 理解する when you say  「(私は)このビデオの内容**を**60％ぐらい理解できます。」. In 「このビデオの内容**は**６０％ぐらい理解できます」, を is replaced by は (so it's not there but it's still implied), and 60%ぐらい functions adverbially (so you don't need to add を to ～ぐらい)